# I need help on CSS grid problem where I have to use column-templates

Tags: css, css-grid

http://cssgridgarden.com

I am trying to solve this game where you need to put water to the plants and pollutions to the weeds. I am on level 24 and I don't have a clue on how to solve this one. I feel like this question is too simple but I really need some help on this. I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score -1):

```
grid-column-start: 3
```

[You can take a look at this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)